# font-family does not fall back to the next font in line

Tags: css, font-family

When I set `font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;` **Roboto** is rendered.

But if I add Helvetica `font-family: Helvetica, Roboto, sans-serif;` , then **Arial** is rendered.

*Tested in Chrome 99 and Firefox 98 on Windows 11. On my system there's Roboto installed and Arial preinstalled. Helvetica is not.*

Why doesn't it fall back to **Roboto** since its the next font in line?

Answer (score 0):

Problem might be in your way of writing **font-family**.
If you have newly installed font, you should use quotes, maybe also for Arial if is preinstalled.

```
font-family: Helvetica, 'Roboto', sans-serif;
```